Automated git message formatting
I am looking for automated way to create commit message of specified format in Git. So that, when I type git commit, I would see Vim editor with already preformatted commit message, like this:
[branch_name] ...

# Some normal automatically generated Git comments

Branch name needs to be automatically set to current branch name.
I tried to use git commit templates, as in this question Custom Git Commit Message Template, but they don't provide automatic template filling, so branch name still needs to be set manually.
Please, could someone give some hint with this?

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg

@dan1st, yes, this is mostly it, though it is not exactly as I imagined the approach, but still, should work. I'll provide solution in the answer to the question, if all is OK. Thank you!
